# $x^2 = 2044 \pmod{2408}$ find all the solutions

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

This is what I have so far:

[image]

I am stuck on how to solve $z^2 = 28 \pmod{56}$ I could continue to keep splitting it into primes but is there a method to find the solutions without a prime modulo?

Comment: Don't bother.  $2408 = 8\times 7\times 43$ so solve $\pmod 8,7$ and $43$

Comment: " I could continue to keep splitting it into primes but is there a method to find the solutions without a prime modulo"  why would you want to *avoid* prime modulo?  They make things much easier and making things much easier is the entire *point* of the chinese remainder theorem...And if you do $x^2 = 28 + 56k$ then as $4$ divides $28+56$ we'd have $2|x$ so we'd solve $y^2 = 7 + 14k$ and we are back to solve $\pmod 7$ anyway.

Comment: There is a mistake in your handwritten code. if(i%$2048$==$0$)...should read $2408$. Highly inefficient algorithm though, at the very least, just take it to the square root.

Comment: @fleablood I didn't think Chinese Remainder Theorem worked for squared congruencies. Also 2044 is divisible by 7 which would mean $z^2 = 0 (mod 7)$

Comment: @fleablood Actually I don't even need chinese remainder theorem because I can solve all the congruences separately

Comment: Chinese remainder theorem will break $M \equiv k \pmod{complexproduct}$ to a series of $M \equiv \pmod {simplevalue}$ and it doesn't matter what $M$ is, it could be a square which you solve *later* by other methods after you have split it apart by CRT.

Comment: $$y\equiv b\pmod m\implies y=mx+b$$ has $$y^2\equiv b^2\pmod{2m}$$ if $$2\mid m$$